# Gpg4Win's Kleopatra can only store one keyserver

Tags: windows-10, gnupg, gpg4win, kleopatra

I want to push my public key to several key servers, but Kleopatra seems to accept only one key server.

All attempts to add new key servers fail, in the sense that I can add, but whenever I press OK and exit the configuration dialog, when I get back the newly-added server will be gone.

How do I specify more than one keyserver in Kleopatra?

PS: I'm using Windows 10 64-bit, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most OpenPGP key servers synchronize among each others. The largest set of key servers are connected to the [SKS key server pool](https://sks-keyservers.net/overview-of-pools.php), if you share your key with one of them, it gets replicated to all others. Some others are also connected through some other synchronization methods like mails sent between key servers.

With other words: choose one of the key servers in the pool, and you're fine. All relevant defaults (`keys.gnupg.net`, `pool.sks-keyservers.net`, the Linux distribution's key servers) are all contained in the pool, or even randomly reference a random server in the pool.

After uploading the key, there is some delay while the key gets replicated. Until all key servers have the updated information, some minutes or rarely hours might pass.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure that keys.gnupg.net and pool.sks-keyservers.net (and possibly other pools) replicate with each other. Now I can have peace of mind 